# What is feature module for instant app support in android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, android-studio-3.0

From android studio 3.0 Instant App Support has been added. When I created a project and if Instant app support enabled for the project then its ask for configuring the feature module name like below:
[image]

My question is what is this feature module name and what should be its name?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can name it as you want, for your first feature module you can choose a stuff like myapp-base.
If you haven't you can check this codelabs : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/#0
NB : don't forget to edit the package name to fit yours ;)

Regards,